# How can we import time series data from csv in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv, time-series

I want to read time series data from csv in Matlab. My data looks like,

> 2020-04-01, 0, 1, 5, 2, 3

> 2020-04-02, 2, 1, 4, 4, 0

I have tried this below, but I got an error message.

```
data = readtable('time_series.csv');
date = data(:,1);
date = datetime(date, 'InputFormat', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

> ```
> Error using datetime (line 617)
> Input data must be a numeric or a cell array or char matrix containing date/time strings.
> ```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Is `data(:, 1)` a numeric or cell array or a char matrix?

Comment: `data(:,1)` would be a table and `data{:,1}` would be a `datetime` array. So, the `date=datetime(...)` conversion on line 3 has two issues: 1. can't convert a table and 2. values are already datetime values in column 1 from `readtable`